# Check if your Application has created an event or not

Tags: facebook, events, facebook-graph-api

The Facebook API lets applications only edit events that they've created. But is there a way to check if an event was created by your app (using the Graph API or FQL)?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but as your statement says ,the API let you edit the event only if the that application has created it.So you can just try to edit an event and if it returns false it means your application has not created it.

Comment: yes, that would be an option, but I need to know that before making another call to try editing the event.

Comment: @PierreValade Again this will be an inefficient process,but if there is no option for that,you can do it in two steps:1,lets get the location of the event.2,try to edit the event using that "location" only,this way you will not be editing anything and at the same time will get if your application has created that event or not

Comment: Thanks, nice hack but basically the answer is that it's not easy.